# Use roboguice out of roboactivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, guice, roboguice

I've a roboactivity where I inject some stuff like resources and views. I use some fragment classes in my app. These fragments have to extend Fragment. Here is my stuff:

When a button is pressed I make a new fragment:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame,Fragment.instantiate(this,fragments[position]));
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

My fragment looks like this:

```
public class MyLists extends Fragment {
    @InjectView(R.id.myview)
    private TextView myview;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_lists_fragment, null);

        MyRepo repo= new MyRepo ();

        myview.setText(repo.getSomething());
        return root;
    }
}
```

The InjectView isn't working. I can't find the reason why it wont work. Can anybody help me solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injection happens during `onViewCreated` which is after `onCreateView`. Move your code to `onViewCreated`.

On an `Activity` there is `setContentView` where injection can take place. On a fragment, you return the view so robojuice can't know to use that for injection until later.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_lists_fragment, null);
    // Here you've inflated something, but robojuice has no way of knowing
    // that's the fragments view at this point, and no base method has been called
    // that robojuice might use to find your View.
    // So myview is still null here:
    myview.setText(repo.getSomething());
    return root;
}
```